# Let $x_n$ be a bounded sequence and for each $n$ in $N$ let $s_n:= \sup\{x_k: k>=n\}$ and $S:= \inf{s_n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that there exists a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $S$.

I would guess that $s_n$ has a finite (or zero) peaks, just because the supremum should always be larger than the last, so its monotone increasing, or the first supremum is the largest, so it is constant. So I would want a subsequence that converges to the first supremum of $s_n$, because that would be the infinum of the set. Is this correct, and if so, how would I go about finding this subsequence?

Comment: $s_n$ is a monotonic bounded sequence, therefore it converges. You should then use the definition of $\inf$ to conclude that $S$ must be that limit.

Comment: How would I go about proving it is monotonic? Is the intuitional reason sufficient?

Comment: $s_n$ is supremum of some quantity over a set. If $m>n$, then $s_m$ is the supremum of the same quantity, but over a strictly *smaller* set. Now, you can see why $s_n$ is monotonic decreasing(this reasoning is sufficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$s_n$ is monotonically decreasing (because for $m>n$ we have $s_m <= s_n$).

Since $s_n$ is bounded (because $x_n$ is bounded) it converges to the infimum.

This can be shown by the definition of the inf.

So, $\exists$a sequence ${\{n_k\}} $ such that $x_{n_k}\to S$, namely $s_n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Intuitive fact: If $A\subseteq B,$ then $\sup A\leq \sup B.$**

Firstly, note that the sequence $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a decreasing sequence. Indeed, for any two natural numbers $m < n,$ since 
$$\{ n,n+1,n+2,... \}  \subseteq \{ m,m+1,m+2,... \},$$
by the fact above, we have 
$$s_n\leq s_m.$$
Therefore, $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is decreasing.

Since $(s_n)$ is a subsequence of a bounded sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty,$ the subsequence $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is also bounded.

By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, the sequence $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges. 
**Recall that any bounded decreasing sequence will converge to its infimum**, that is, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}s_n = S.$$